# Button Press back to other activity

Tags: android, button, save

Hello everyone i made an mobile application where you can save your car details in the database but how can i go back to the main activity the moment somebody entered their values and clicked on save i have the following code

```
SaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                InsertCar();
                Return true();
            }
    });
```

The moment the user clicks on save i need to go back to main activity automaticly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this one in activity:

```
finish();
```

Comment: it closes the whole application

Comment: when you open new activity , don't finish MainActivity Or before Finishing this Activity start MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

if this activity is on top of your `MainActivity` call `finish()` inside the `onClickLisnter` of current activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up in the manifest

In the activity tag add:

Android:parentActivityName=com.mainActivity

Then in your activity : finish();

Answer (score 0):

In order to terminate the current activity you can simply call `finish();` after the `InsertCar();`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is below.You can use in click function.

`YourController.super.onBackPressed();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            this.finish();
        }
});
```